# How to add Dynamic external scripts in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Have two portals in angular and both have different styles, so i want to add style on load component, Style added but not loaded. Please help me to implement

Here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";

export interface type {
  fileName: string;
  fileType: string;
}

const externalScripts: type[] = [
  { fileName: "src/assets/blk-design-system.css", fileType: "css" },
  { fileName: "src/assets/nucleo-icons.css", fileType: "css" }
];

@Component({
  selector: "app-layout",
  templateUrl: "./layout.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./layout.component.css"]
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScripts();
  }

  loadScripts() {
    externalScripts.forEach(element => {
      // this.scriptLoader.loadJsCssFiles(element.fileName, element.fileType);
      this.loadStyle(element.fileName);
    });
  }

  loadStyle(styleName: string) {
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    const style = this.document.createElement("link");
    style.id = "client-theme";
    style.rel = "stylesheet";
    style.href = `${styleName}`;

    head.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

---

**Here is the Output**

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Hi,

I also need to implement the same in one of my project so I took the help from this below link... please visit so that you will have clear understanding of how to import JavaScript dynamically in angular.


https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use any styling outside of your component, you need to import it in `src/styles.css` file.

```
@import "assets/blk-design-system.css";
```

If you find any files that are already imported like bootstrap just add the import line beneath it.

To prevent encapsulation within a component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-layout",
    templateUrl: "./layout.component.html",
    styleUrls: [
    "./layout.component.css",
    //include external css here
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
})
```

and include external css in styleUrls

Comment: But this will implement on whole project, i have two portals in one project that have different css and js so i need to define it separately

Comment: Well, then your only is to disable encapsulation.